# C++ how to use any_of for finding duplicate number in function?

Tags: c++

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void input_guess_number(int guess_number[]){

    int num, check = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        cout << "please enter no." << i+1 << " number (0-9) and press enter: ";
        cin >> num;

        if (any_of(begin(guess_number), end(guess_number), [=](int n){return n == num;})){
            check = 1;
        }
        else{
            check = 0;
        }

        if (check == 1){
            cout << "\nyou cannot use this number. try another one!\n\n";
            i--;
        }
        else if (num >=0 && num < 10){
            guess_number[i] = num;
        }
        else{
            cout << "\nwrong number! please choose a number from 0 to 9.\n\n";
            i--;
        }

    }

    cout << "\nYour number is: ";

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << guess_number[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int guess_number[4] = {100, 100, 100, 100};
    input_guess_number(guess_number);
}
```

they works well if I put all code in the main().

now I am trying to put them to a function input_guess_number,
so that the main() will be smaller.
but something happened. they cannot work.

anyone know how to improve this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> anyone know how to improve this? thanks.

Yes, make the length of the array deducable through a template

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<std::size_t Length>
void input_guess_number(int (&guess_number)[Length])
{

    int num, check = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < Length ; i++){

        cout << "please enter no." << i+1 << " number (0-9) and press enter: ";
        cin >> num;

        if (any_of(begin(guess_number), end(guess_number), [=](int n){return n == num;})){
            check = 1;
        }
        else{
            check = 0;
        }

        if (check == 1){
            cout << "\nyou cannot use this number. try another one!\n\n";
            i--;
        }
        else if (num >=0 && num < 10){
            guess_number[i] = num;
        }
        else{
            cout << "\nwrong number! please choose a number from 0 to 9.\n\n";
            i--;
        }

    }

    cout << "\nYour number is: ";

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << guess_number[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int guess_number[4] = {100, 100, 100, 100};
    input_guess_number(guess_number);
}
```

for fun, here's a version which uses `std::vector` to accumulate the digits, and also shows which remaining digits are allowed in the prompt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

vector<pair<int, int>> allowed_range(int min, int max, const std::vector<int>& used)
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> result;

    while (min != max)
    {
        while ((min != max) && std::find(begin(used), end(used), min) != end(used))
        {
            ++min;
        }

        if (min != max)
        {
            pair<int, int> current = { min, min };
            while ((min != max) && std::find(begin(used), end(used), min+1) == end(used))
                ++min;
            current.second = min;
            result.push_back(current);
            if (min == max) break;
            ++min;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

std::ostream& emit_range(std::ostream& os, const pair<int, int>& range)
{
    if (range.first == range.second) {
        return os << range.first;
    }
    else {
        return os << range.first << "-" << range.second;
    }
}

std::ostream& emit_ranges(std::ostream& os, const vector<pair<int, int>>& ranges)
{
    auto sep = "";
    for (auto& range : ranges) {
        emit_range(os << sep, range);
        sep = ",";
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& emit_ranges(std::ostream& os, int min, int max, const std::vector<int>& used)
{
    return emit_ranges(os, allowed_range(min, max, used));
}

std::vector<int> input_guess_number(std::size_t desired_length)
{
    std::vector<int> accumulator;

    while (accumulator.size() < desired_length)
    {
        cout << "please enter no." << accumulator.size() + 1 << " number in range ";
        emit_ranges(cout, 0, 9, accumulator) << " and press enter: ";
        int num;
        cin >> num;

        if (std::find(begin(accumulator), end(accumulator), num) != end(accumulator))
        {
            cout << "\nyou cannot use this number. try another one!\n\n";
            continue;
        }
        else if (num < 0 or num > 9) {
            cout << "\nwrong number! please choose a number from 0 to 9.\n\n";
            continue;
        }
        else {
            accumulator.push_back(num);
        }
    }

    return accumulator;
}

int main()
{
    auto digits = input_guess_number(4);
    cout << "\nYour number is: ";
    std::copy(begin(digits), end(digits), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: thanks. this works too, and it seems using the core knowledge of C++.I will try to learn more about this.

Comment: @TankVvv added another version using `std::vector`. It also computes the remaining (unused) digits and expresses them in the output as a compressed range sequence. Thought you might find it instructive.

Comment: nice, thanks a lot. :)  this one had so many things I don't know before.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that once you have passed the array to the function, it has decays to a *pointer* to its first element. You can't really use `begin` and `end` of pointers. Instead pass the size of the array (the number of elements) to the function as an extra argument and use `guess_number` as the start iterator and `guess_number + size_of_array` as the end iterator.

Or start using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for your arrays instead.

Comment: @Rakete1111 You're right, I was wrong. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: thanks. :) after modify it to: if (any_of(guess_number, guess_number+4, [=](int n){return n == num;})). works like a charm.